# Symfony 2.7 - Service is not loaded/registered

Tags: symfony, service, symfony-2.7

Working on Symfony 2.7 -

I created a new service (**ipad.registerchecksum**) in a custom bundle and now I try to use it as an argument in another service (**ipad.download_history**) in another custom bundle but I get the following error :

> The service "ipad.download_history" has a dependency on a non-existent
>   service "ipad.registerchecksum".

Creation of my service :

```
<?php

namespace MyCompany\MyBundle2\Services;

class Registerchecksum
{

    public function sayHello()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }

}

?>
```

Register my class as Service :

```
#MyCompany\MyBundle2\Resources\Config\services.yml

services:
    ipad.registerchecksum:
        class: MyCompany\MyBundle2\Services\Registerchecksum
```

Load my services.yml :

```
<?php

namespace MyCompany\MyBundle2\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;


class MyBundle2Extension extends Extension
{

    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('datagrid/datagrids.yml');
        $loader->load('navigation.yml');
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }

    // Please note : navigation.yml and datagrid/datagrids.yml are well loaded and work perfectly

}
?>
```

.. the service seems not to be registered.

- If I test "/app/console container:debug", it doesn't appear.
- I already clean caches (dev & prod), warmup caches too.

Comment: Seems like a day for mysteries.  Verify that you added your service to the correct services.yml file and double check the spelling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ rm -rf app/cache/*

```
#MyCompany\MyBundle2\Resources\Config\services.yml

services:
    ipad.registerchecksum:
        class: MyCompany\MyBundle2\Services\Registerchecksum

    ipad.download_history:
        class: Your Service
        arguments: ["@ipad.registerchecksum"]
```

Comment: Wooow that's work ! So, I had to register both services in the same services.yml file ... ok.

PS : "rm -rf app/cache/*" is already what I used !

Comment: @Paolito75 There is no actual requirement for dependencies to be in the same file.  As long as you are good with this approach then fine.  But you still have something else going on.

Comment: @Cerad Yes you're right, i wonder if it may be an issue from the APC cache or similar ? Problem is I can't have access on it to check :(